# CoffeeScript - compile all .coffee files in current directory and all sub-directories

Tags: coffeescript

What is the easiest way to compile all .coffee files in the current directory and all sub-directories?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are using *nix systems:

```
find -name "*.coffee" -exec coffee -c {} \;
```

and you may also consider using `Guard`: https://github.com/guard/guard-coffeescript

Comment: @TrevorBurnham Nice feature. Ignorant me.

Comment: `find` is not a very good answer. With `coffee -wc .` the compilation happens whenever you change a `*.coffee` file in the directory

Comment: Please select the [correct and simple answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17220628/104746) that has been given below: coffee -c .

Comment: There are cases were you might want to use "find". 

Here's what I tried: 
* `coffee -cw` : starts the repl
* `coffee -cw *` : Will attempt to compile ALL files including JS, CSS, etc
* `coffee -cw *.coffee` : says "file not found", even though I have coffee files in directories below.

In these cases, "find" is the only way I can get it to work, unless someone has a better suggestion.

Answer (score 68):

you can do so with the integrated `coffee` shell tool:

```
coffee --output lib --compile src
```

compiles a directory tree of .coffee files in `src` into a parallel tree of .js files in `lib`.
Check http://coffeescript.org/#usage for more details

Comment: That is the 'coffeescript way' although I often use guard.

Comment: The question refers to "the current directory," so you want `.`, not `src`. And if you're outputting each `.js` file into the same directory as the `.coffee` file it was compiled from, you don't need `--output`. So: `coffee -c .`

Answer (score 20):

```
coffee -c .
```

Thanks @TrevorBurnham

Answer (score 4):

```
coffee --watch --compile .
```

or

```
coffee -wc .
```

Either of these commands will run forever, watching for *.coffee files in the current directory, and compiling those *.coffee files into *.js JavaScript files whenever the *.coffee files are changed.

If you want the *.js files to be generated into some other directory, just add --output or -o, like this:

```
coffee --watch --output lib --compile src
```

or

```
coffee -w -o lib -c src
```