# This shows a strange error while compiling

Tags: compiler-errors, coffeescript

The command that I learnt to compile all the coffeescript files in a given folder automatically is

> coffee -wc *.coffee

But this throws an error:

`File not found : C:\Users\Tilak\Documents\Tutorials\node_modules\*.coffee`

Why is that ?

**NOTE**: I don't want the below command as answer, I know that but it compiles only one file
      at a time

> coffee --compile filename.coffee

Comment: First guess: because its windows and not unix.

Comment: Yeah its windows , so ..

Comment: I'm not a windows guy. Is that how the wildcard selector works from the windows command prompt? Because that code you put up works fine in linux/OSX.

Comment: @Jaden Smith yeah it does, for example , `dir *.txt ` will display all the text files in the directory

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8818574/3757232

Comment: Yeah, thanks !! that works ~ By the way I sorry it was @Jared NOT "Jaden Smith" (he is a popular actor !)

Comment: Works bud! just answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
coffee --output lib --compile src
```

it compiles a directory tree of .coffee files in src into a parallel tree of .js files in lib.

Comment: Sorry how I referred to you as Jaden Smith !

Comment: You could just use bash (comes with Git, Cygwin or even native in Win10) or PowerShell (preinstalled in Windows7+) instead of `cmd.exe`. All of them support wildcards, `cmd.exe` does not and I would generally avoid it.